# How to transform maven pom tag <snapshot> into gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, pom.xml

I want to use an sql parsing library from [github](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser):
The page says, that the following `Maven` tags are needed in `pom.xml` to import it.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jsqlparser-snapshots</id>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jsqlparser</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, I am using gradle. So the `dependency` section in the above `pom.xml` would transform into `gradle.build` more or less like that:

```
dependencies {
    compile("com.github.jsqlparser:jsqlparser:1.1")
}
```

But I don't know how to transform the content of `repository` tag, particulary `snapshot` and `url`.

Comment: If you need a specific jsqlparser feature hat is already implemented in the snapshot, file an release issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to use snapshot builds, which is latest development version that might break stuff inadvertently? If not, you read the instructions wrongly. You can simply use `mavenCentral()` or `jcenter()` as Gradle repository for your build to get the latest released version of that library.

If you really want the snapshot versions, you use `maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public' }` and use `x.y-SNAPSHOT` in the version, or something like `x.+` for the latest available version, including snapshot versions. You don't need to specially enable snapshot version usage with Gradle.